# running Catarse on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just deployed my Catarse app to Heroku and need help with the error logs.  The App will not load. I have run the migrations and setup all necessary plugins.  here is my log output
This app runs just fine locally and I an not getting any issues until I push to Heroku.

```
2013-01-08T19:54:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-01-08T19:55:20+00:00 app[web.1]: Dalli/SASL authenticating as app10788718%40heroku.com
2013-01-08T19:55:20+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:20+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:20+00:00 app[web.1]: Dalli/SASL: Authenticated
2013-01-08T19:55:20+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/en" for 66.37.82.222 at 2013-01-08 19:55:20 +0000
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset.
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass)
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/a
pplication.css.sass)):
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [Airbrake] Failure: Net::HTTPClientError
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [Airbrake] Environment Info: [Ruby: 1.9.2] [Rails: 3.2.7] [Env: production]
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Your account is being provisioned or no longer active.
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [Airbrake] Response from Airbrake:
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:25:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_slim___1907562053076719698_60592900'
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:     /[if lt IE 9]
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1030ms
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProjectsController#index as HTML
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:       meta property="fb:app_id" content=Configuration['site.facebook_app_id']
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:       meta property="og:description" content==(t('projects.index_header.title') + '. ' +  t('projects.index_header.subtitle'))
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:       = javascript_include_tag "http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:     = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => 'screen, projection'
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass:1
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:     = yield :js_templates
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered projects/_recommended_header.html.slim (77.0ms)
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered projects/index.html.slim within layouts/application (291.9ms)
2013-01-08T19:55:27+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:27+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:27+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:27+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.37.82.222 at 2013-01-08 19:55:27 +0000
2013-01-08T19:55:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProjectsController#index as HTML
2013-01-08T19:55:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://catarse-lake.herokuapp.com/en
2013-01-08T19:55:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as :detect_locale rendered or redirected
2013-01-08T19:55:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/en host=catarse-lake.herokuapp.com fwd=66.37.82.222 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=193ms status=500 bytes=728
2013-01-08T19:55:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/en" for 66.37.82.222 at 2013-01-08 19:55:27 +0000
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered projects/_recommended_header.html.slim (1.8ms)
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [Airbrake] Failure: Net::HTTPClientError
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [Airbrake] Environment Info: [Ruby: 1.9.2] [Rails: 3.2.7] [Env: production]
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [Airbrake] Response from Airbrake:
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Your account is being provisioned or no longer active.
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered projects/index.html.slim within layouts/application (11.8ms)
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset.
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass)
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass)):
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:       meta property="fb:app_id" content=Configuration['site.facebook_app_id']
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:       meta property="og:description" content==(t('projects.index_header.title') + '. ' +  t('projects.index_header.subtitle'))
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:     = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => 'screen, projection'
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:     /[if lt IE 9]
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:       = javascript_include_tag "http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:     = yield :js_templates
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass:1
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:25:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_slim___1907562053076719698_60592900'
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms
2013-01-08T19:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProjectsController#index as HTML
2013-01-08T19:55:27+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=catarse-lake.herokuapp.com fwd=66.37.82.222 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=10ms status=302 bytes=102
2013-01-08T19:55:24+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/en host=catarse-lake.herokuapp.com fwd=66.37.82.222 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=2ms connect=2ms service=4406ms status=500 bytes=728
```

Answer (score 0):

so the issue here was in production.rb

this line
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: ::Configuration[:host] }

was throwing a uninitialized constant Configuration and preventing the 
assets compiler from running.

so i removed the line and all is fine.   comments about why and how to fix would be welcomed

Comment: this is fixed in the newest commit